# Nginx server laravel route directory 404 error

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

Recently I have Installed Laravel in Nginx. Laravel application home page works fine but route page gets 404 error.
My `Nginx` configuration is below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /var/www/html;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

When I access url like `localhost/lar/public`, it works fine.
Routes are declared but when I access URL like `localhost/lar/public/test`, it gets 404 error.

Comment: Have you properly configured `APP_URL` in your `.env` file?

Comment: Yeah, I have properly configured APP_URL in .env file. But still not works

Comment: You should set your root to something like `root /home/user_name/Documents/laravel_project_name/public;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just Changed root to /var/www/html/lar/public, then routes works properly